# Headphone stops working when I start using Skype

Tags: windows, skype

When I start using Skype my headphones stop working and laptops loud speaker starts to work. What could cause this?
EDIT: Whenever someone calls, the issue again occurs and I have to unplug and plug the headphone back to use it.

Operating System: Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds like Skype is causing this... What have you tried? Did you search for this issue? I believe you may find several questions already answered that will help you.

Comment: Configure Skype to use your headphones instead of your speakers as its output device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout your settings in Skype:

Tools-->General-->Audio Settings-->Speakers-->Select "Headphones" from drop down. Currently, it must be in Speaker rather than Headphones.

Hope this helps.